# aura render event: DOM update issue

Tags: aura, dynamic, dom, rendering

This question relates to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358554/unescapedhtml-js-event/359642#359642), where we got rid of the unescapedHtml tag to rather use render event for dynamic DOM manipulation.
My new issue is the following:

I'm listening to the aura "render" event, to be able to dynamically insert elements to the DOM at render time. For some reason, erratically, the content is sometimes not set in the DOM.
We use a property 'v.messages', an array containing sanitized html strings, for content injection.
cmp side:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.messages}" var="message">
   <p class="slds-text-body text-bubble">
      <!-- Content dynamically set via doRender  -->
    </p>
    <!-- Other content here -->
    <!-- ... -->
</aura:iteration>
```

Render JS handler:

```
doRender: function (component, event, helper) {
   // Inject messages
   var messageContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("text-bubble");
   if (messageContainers.length > 0) {
   var messages = component.get("v.messages");
   for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
     var message = messages[i],
     container = messageContainers[i];

     // Set message html content
     container.innerHTML = message.messageText;
    }
  }
}
```

When the content is not set, obviously we don't see anything via developer inspector :
[image: dev inspector]

Am I missing an obvious point, or am I wrong in the approach ?

Comment: Just to clarify your code, you are implying/assuming that if there are multiple "messages", that there are corresponding "containers" (using the [i] index for both) - but your example doesn't show multiple containers.  If that wasn't intentional, perhaps that may be related to your issue.

Comment: Indeed, there are several <p> text-bubble containers created through the iteration tag, looping over messages !